# 【Tomcat9】Is it possible to set a property "maxHttpHeaderSize" on AJP1.3 connector?

Tags: web, tomcat, tomcat9, ajp

Server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443"
           secretRequired="true"
           secret="MyApp"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="10000" />
```

This doesn't work. In an initialization log of Tomcat says it can't set a property "maxHttpHeaderSize" by warning level.

How can I change a limitation about the size of request-header?

Answer (score 1):

AJP does not support maxHttpHeaderSize you should use [packetSize](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Standard_Implementations) instead.

I should also add that it was necessary to change [ProxyIOBufferSize](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyiobuffersize).